# CSS flex display acts differently with same flex items in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, flexbox

I have several same flex items, containing a rectangle `span` with `margin-right`, and a `text span` scaled due to the font-size limitation of browsers like Chrome. I put them into a flex container but I figured that some of them are incorrect in Chrome, without `margin-right` of the rect `span`, but Firefox is fine.

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 2.1875px;
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
}

.rect {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(6, 74, 105);
  margin-right: 0.875px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left center;
  width: 20.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span class="rect"></span>
    <span class="text">Mazda</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span class="rect"></span>
    <span class="text">Mazda</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span class="rect"></span>
    <span class="text">Mazda</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span class="rect"></span>
    <span class="text">Mazda</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span class="rect"></span>
    <span class="text">Mazda</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code snippet run result is correct, too. But not in https://jsfiddle.net/xgahLv3k/1/

Here is the demo image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWDba.png), the second item's rectangle has no margin-right.

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Its so tiny, its impossible to tell whether there is a space or not! Is that the actual size in your site?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes I have to keep a small size. So is it caused by the too-small space?

Comment: @FluffyKitten oh I set the rect span's margin-right to 1px and it works well now! thank you so much! do you want to post an answer then I can accept it?

Comment: How can we justify that the second item rectangle has no margin-right. Here code doesn't work, then we can solve either suggest, but there is no problem in u r code then close this question.

Comment: @chandukomati Because I saw no gap in the demo image so I called it `no margin-right`.  Now I know that it is because the px value is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser calculates the space in its own way, so when we are dealing with fractions of pixels there can be slight discrepancies. This can be further complicated by anything that causes further calculations, such as the use of flex, or scale transitions.

The best way to deal with this is to use full pixels - if you think about it, a pixels are theoretically the smallest unit for the screen display so fractions of pixels don't make sense, and the browser has to make compensations to deal with such values.

The below snippet uses whole pixels for `.flex-item` and `.rect` as follows:

```
.flex-item {
  margin-right: 2px;
  /* rest of CSS */
}

.rect {
  margin-right: 1px;
  /* rest of CSS */
}
```

They were 2.1875px +  0.875px so now it adds up to a nice round total of 3px

**Working Snippet:**

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
}

.rect {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(6, 74, 105);
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left center;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <span class="rect"></span>
      <span class="text">Mazda</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <span class="rect"></span>
      <span class="text">Mazda</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <span class="rect"></span>
      <span class="text">Mazda</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <span class="rect"></span>
      <span class="text">Mazda</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <span class="rect"></span>
      <span class="text">Mazda</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes, that makes sense, thank you! BTW, do you know why the rectangle looks slightly different with 5px height and 5px width, for example, the second and the third one in your result?

Comment: @soundquiet They look ok to me, and I've inspected them using the element inspector and they are all exactly 5px * 5px. I'm not sure why you are seeing them differently. Its not to do with the square, but for the text how come you are using font 12 and then scaling it 50%? Font-size 6px will get the same without any potential side effects of scaling. Also, your container is only 50px which is not wide enough for the contents - its overflowing at the moment but it could cause problems if you have adjacent elements in your project.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, pixels are the smallest unit that you can use. This means pixels smaller than 1 get rounded to either 0px or 1px depending on the rounding behavior on the browser. In your case, `rect` class has margin-right smaller than 1px. Just try to avoid using pixel that is smaller than 1px.